# mediaelement position setting problem

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

i use this line to set my media element position

```
OurElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(NowPlayingParameters.Position);
```

but it stays 00:00 why can't it jump to the position value

Answer (score 5):

You should wait for the `MediaOpened` event before attempting to set the `Position`

```
OurElement.MediaOpened += (s, args) => 
{
  OurElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(NowPlayingParameters.Position);
}
```

Comment: This approach shows the first frame of the video... :( I'd like skip first frame  it and play N seconds later. Is it possible to do?